# nvidia driver 14.04 install fails

Tags: nvidia, dell, inspiron

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 9300 with a new HD.   Was working reasonably well, but was getting a 'black screen of death' with messages about problems with the nouveau driver and the nvidia card.

My Dell has the Nvidia GeForce Go 6800 v84.30.  The Dell is running with bios A04 -- I have not found a linux version of the A05 bios - only windows

I downloaded and tried to install a driver from nvidia,  NVIDIA-Linux-x86-185.18.36.pkg1.run.   Part of the pre-install had the nouveau driver put in a 'blacklist'.   The actual install fails with messages about kernel configuration:
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation 
   anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> No precompiled kernel interface was found to match your kernel; would you li
   ke the installer to attempt to download a kernel interface for your kernel f
   rom the NVIDIA ftp site (ftp://download.nvidia.com)? (Answer: Yes)
-> No matching precompiled kernel interface was found on the NVIDIA ftp site;
   this means that the installer will need to compile a kernel interface for
   your kernel.
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
-> Performing CC version check with CC="cc".
ERROR: The kernel header file
       '/lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/build/include/linux/version.h' does not
       exist.  The most likely reason for this is that the kernel source files
       in '/lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/build' have not been configured.

I have searched around and found suggestions for different packages - nothing makes any difference - I get the same error.

The system does work-kinda.   Very slow and I get messages about running graphics thru the CPU rather than the graphics card.

I have worked with linux before, but this is my first personal physical linux laptop -- mostly used VM's on top of Windows for work.

Suggestions?   Please be detailed and not assume I know squat.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! There is not a very clear question asked here. It needs to be edited or removed. See http://askubuntu.com/tour. This is more appropriate for http://ubuntuforums.org/. It's a common mistake to confuse the etiquette  of the forums and this website on your first try, so don't worry.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the nvidia driver from ubuntu software-center.

Open ubuntu software-center, click edit and select software sources. Click on Aditional Drivers and from there you can select the proprietary driver from the list of drivers. The most stable version is the one marked "tested".

Comment: very nice, glad someone finally posted this! Everywhere else I go there are complex 'works-on-my-machine' terminal hacks. More people should know this solution!

Comment: OMG, you are a LIFE SAVER, I've been jacking around with that stupid .run file or hour trying to figure out how to install the damn thing.  The software center was easy, why isn't in the display options or system settings is beyond me :(

Comment: @csharptest.net the official nvidia driver is proprietary (non-free) and so the open source equivalent driver (nouveau) is installed by default. Also, now that it's installed you actually should have extra display settings available for nvidia.